# Capacitance of a plate capacitor with a piece of electrical conductor inside

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, capacitance

Given a plate capacitor and a piece of electric conductor between the plates, what would be the formula for the capacitance of such capacitor? How do I get it? On the image Cu is taken just for example.

[image: Illustration]

Answer (score 2):

I assume that $d$ and $h$ are much smaller than $L$ and $l$, then this system will be equivalent to two parallel plate capacitors connected in parallel. One made by the still uncovered part of the lower plate and the opposing part of the upper plate, and the other made by the upper surface of the Cu block and its opposing part of the upper plate. The two capacitors are in parallel configuration since they share the same terminals.